# How to convert geometry string like "POLYGON ((32.5 39.2, 32.6 39.4 .... ))" to GeoJSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

I have strings like

```
POLYGON ((32.5 39.2, 32.6 39.4 .... ))
POINT (32.4 39.2)
```

using Leaflet, React is there a way to convert these string to GeoJSON like:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

in JavaScript?

Comment: Why don't you parse the string with a regex, then use a `map` function or some kind of another iterator?

Comment: There are 5 different geometry types, and if there is any library doing job, I would not write the code again =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These strings are called WKT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry).

There are quite a few parsers out there:
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=wkt

"wellknown" and "wicket" can output GeoJSON, probably there are other modules that support this too.

Note that WKT represents just "geometry" field in GeoJSON, content of "properties" field should come from somewhere else (say if this was CSV - from other CSV columns).